# Почему не срабатывает скрипт (ошибка ActionController::UnknownFormat)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, хочу реализовать ajax голосование на сайте с использованием гема acts_as_votable.
Есть такой код:

```
  def upvote
    @answer.upvote_from current_user, :vote_weight =>  1
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

В папке views/answers добавил файл upvote.js.erb и там для начала прописал простой console.log.
Но вместо вывода сообщения в консоль получаю ошибку  ActionController::UnknownFormat. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?
Код вьюхи для ответа:

```
      = link_to like_answer_path(answer),  class: "like", method: :put do
        button.btn.btn-info aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-up.glyphicon-align-center aria-hidden="true"
          span.badge= answer.get_upvotes.size
      = link_to unlike_answer_path(answer), class: "like", method: :put do
        button.btn.btn-info aria-label=("Left Align") type="button"
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-down.glyphicon-align-center aria-hidden="true"
          span.badge= answer.get_downvotes.size
```

Comment: Эта ошибка означает, что на присланный запрос respond_to нечего ответить. Причиной ошибки является присланный запрос. Приложите его.

Comment: @D-side Хмм, код связанный с методом upvote я указал, в upvote.js.erb в данный момент написано alert("hello"). Что ещё нужно?

Comment: То, что в этот метод стучится.

Comment: Не понимаю( Добавил код вьюхи. Перед методом upvote срабатывает before_action, но там просто поиск ответа по id -> @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])

Comment: Много лишнего, достаточно ссылки на "лайк". Да, естественно, падает уже respond_to, до него всё работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: в вызове `link_to` для лайка не хватает `remote: true`.

Ссылка делает обычный (не AJAX) запрос от лица браузера, которому нужна **веб-страница** или, на худой конец, текст, чтобы открыть содержимое в текущем окне/вкладке. Но это вы можете уточнить, вскрыв совершаемый запрос инспектором (или `pry`!) на предмет заголовка `Accept`.

Браузеру в подобных запросах не нужен JS-ответ. Соответствующего MIME-типа в этом заголовке вы не увидите. Но ваш блок `respond_to` написан так, что он обслуживает только запросы,  просящие JS!

Выглядит это как незаконченная попытка применить `:remote` (эпичный костыль, к сожалению, являющийся частью Rails), который делает означенный запрос с намерением получить от сервера исполняемый JS для изменения текущей загруженной страницы. Только самое начало забыли.

Comment: Агаа, спасибо) Почему то решил, что remote: true нужно прописывать только для форм.